# How do I fix macOS Mojave httpd syntax error in a localhost setup?

Tags: macos, apache, php, webserver

System details:

- OS Host: Mac OS Mojave
- PHP: 7.1.23

I am trying to set up my local server on a new Mac. I have been following the following instructions on https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-13841.

After enabling PHP, perl and personal websites, I check  the configuration with apachectl configtest and the terminal returns the following:

`httpd: Syntax error on line 511 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 16 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf: No matches for the wildcard '*.conf' in '/private/etc/apache2/users', failing (use IncludeOptional if required)`

However, I am expecting syntax OK. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Lack of full configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do actually not have any configuration files in the `/private/etc/apache2/users/` directory, and thus you cannot include them - therefore the configuration check fails.

If you have users on your system with shared a shared Sites folder, you would usually have configuration files in this directory named `username.conf` with the following contents:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

(Note: You'll need to replace "username" in the filename and the contents with the actual name of the user)

Comment: If I create this file will it fix it? From researching online many people are having a similar problem.

Comment: Yes. That’s why I suggested it...